# Icon in ionic list is not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list in my ionic project with some icons that I want to click. But I cannot get the click to be picked up either by the htmll onclick() or by the AngularJS ng-click. My html looks like this:

```html
<ion-view view-title="CUES - WATCH LIST">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="notification-message col-80" ng-hide="hideNotificationMessage" ng-click="hideNotificationMessage=true" ng-bind-html="messageContents"></div>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="watchlistitem in watchlist" href="#/app/trailer/{{watchlistitem.id}}">
        <div class="watchlist-movie-thumb">
          <img class="movie-thumb-image" src="{{watchlistitem.picture}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-75 watchlist-title-genre-container">
          <div class="watchlist-movie-title">
            {{watchlistitem.title}}
          </div>
          <div class="watchlist-movie-genres">
            {{watchlistitem.genres}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="item-icon-right" onclick="alert('you clicked me');" ng-click='remove_movie()'>
          <i class="icon ion-trash-a" style="color:black;padding-top:40px"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="item-icon-right">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-upload-outline" style="color:black;padding-bottom:40px;"></i>
        </a>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The fact that even the onclick() doesn't pick up the click is very odd. I have tried changing the z index to 9999 but that has made no difference.

Comment: are there any messages in your console when you try to click the <a> tag?

Comment: And I'm assuming you can inspect the <a> tag in the console?

Comment: Yes I think the problem may be due to the click being constrained by the ionic ion-item or ion-list

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across an answer by trying every html mod I could think of.

This is a bit of a bodge but works without compromising the layout.

I simply added a margin-right style to the  tag as follows:

```html
<a class="item-icon-right">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-upload-outline" style="margin-right:-2px;color:black;padding-bottom:40px;" ng-click='remove_movie()'></i>
</a>
```

It doesn't seem to matter with respect to fixing the click problem what value I give the margin-right as long as it is there. It does though alter the layout as you would expect.